# How to use `$window.history.back()` to go back in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using `$window.history.back()` to go 1 step back in my Ionic + Angular app.

It has an issue: if my URL is in proper form (`http://localhost:8100/jobs.html`) then it is working properly, but if my URL is in this form (`http://localhost:8100/jobs.html#/category`) then it is not working and does not go back.

Here is my function:

```
$scope.back3=function() {    
    $window.history.back(); 
}
```

I will be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `window.history.go(-1);` in `$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction` event. It will go back on pressing back button key. below is the example :

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($ionicPlatform){
 $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(onBackKeyDown, 100);

  function onBackKeyDown() {
       window.history.go(-1);
    }
 }
});
```

For giving back button action on any button use following code:

HTML

```
<div ng-click="goBack()">Back</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$scope.goBack = function() {
  window.history.back();
};
```

Comment: You can maintain your own stack of URLs so that u can redirect them on previous page on some button.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Ionic Framework history navigation you should also use proper Ionic Framework history object:

Use this if you want to go to the previous view:

```
$ionicHistory.goBack();
```

More about it can be found here: [$ionicHistory](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/)

Comment: var app=angular.module('starter', ['ionic']);
app.controller('linksCtrl', function ($scope,$http,$ionicHistory) {
 $scope.back3 = function () {
        $ionicHistory.goBack();
    }
});

Comment: Can you create a small working example using plnkr.co or any other similar site? Here's one template: http://plnkr.co/edit/cmJYiT?p=info

Comment: @Gajotres is 100% right, you should be using $ionicHistory for this